Cookie shown in cookies tab, but disappears after a second [NextJS & cookies-next]
I'm using cookies-next to set a cookie in NextJS, like so (pages router, client side as per docs):
const cookieOptions = {
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 399), // 399 days (max cookie age in chrome is 400),
};


setCookie("segmentation", segmentation, cookieOptions);

the cookie is properly set, and works, if navigated around the site with normal next js routing:

however, after manually reloading, or closing the tab and coming back to the site, the cookies is shown for a brief second and then disapears.

Well, the issue was, incorrectly set up cookie compliance script, that on load deleted the cookie (ergo why it only deleted on refresh, and not when client-side routing)
Not really helpful I guess, but if anyone is dealing with cookie issues, this is your reminder to check if any external scripts aren't messing it up ;)
